# NoReverseMatch after include Favorite button

Tags: python, html, django, url, django-templates

I'm pretty new at Django framework, and following a tutorial. Although when I tried to include a input button for favorites on my detail.html I got this error:

> Error during template rendering
> In template C:\Users\leo8\Desktop\Lucas\c2view03\webdeve\templates\detail.html, error at line 8
>
> Reverse for 'favorites' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>
> ['webdeve/(?P<Dreams_id>[0-9]+)/favorites/$']
>
> ```
> 1 <img src="{{ dream.imagem }}">
> 2 <h2>{{ dream.titulo }} {{ dream.objetivo }}</h2>
> 3 
> 4 {% if error_message %}
> 5     <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
> 6 {% endif %}
> 7 
> 8 <form action="{% url 'webdeve:favorites' Dreams.id %}" method="post">
> 9     {% csrf_token %}
> 10        {% for which in dream.which_set.all %}
> 11            <input type="radio" id="which{{ forloop.counter }}" name="which" value="{{ titulo.id }}"/>
> 12            <label for="which{{ forloop.counter }}">
> 13                {{ which.make }}
> 14                {% if which.favorites %}
> 15                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/add_16x16.gif" />
> 16                {% endif %}
> 17            </label><br>
> 18        {% endfor %}
> ```

Those are my views:

```
from .models import Dreams, Which
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

app_name = 'webdeve'


def index(request):
    all_dreams = Dreams.objects.all()
    contexto = {'all_dreams': all_dreams}
    return render(request, 'index.html', contexto)


def detail(request, Dreams_id):
    #dream = Dreams.objects.get(pk=Dreams_id)
    dream = get_object_or_404(Dreams, pk=Dreams_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'dream': dream})


def favorites(request, Dreams_id):
    dream = get_object_or_404(Dreams, pk=Dreams_id)
    try:
        selected_which = dream.which_set.get(pk=request.POST['make'])
    except (KeyError, Which.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {
            'dream': dream,
            'error_message': "no which selected"
        })
    else:
        selected_which.favorites = True
        selected_which.save()
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'dream': dream})
```

and myapp.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from webdeve import views

app_name = 'webdeve'

# Dreams

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

# Dreams/detail

    url(r'^(?P<Dreams_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

# Dreams/detail/favoriteS

    url(r'^(?P<Dreams_id>[0-9]+)/favorites/$', views.favorites, name='favorites'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never send `Dreams` to your `form` from your `view`, therefore `Dreams.id` doesn't exist. Try `dream.id` in your template.

Comment: what about
dream = get_object_or_404(Dreams, pk=Dreams_id)
and:
return render(request, 'detail.html', {'dream': dream})

Comment: `Dream != dream`. Python is case sensitive. What's inside the quotes of the context it the name used in the template.

Comment: yeah it worked thank you so much, im getting a problem with no wich found but im gonna try to solve it .
Again thank you so much, Carl;

Comment: Same problem. You don't send 'wich' in the context